# How to replace multiple value in python with the re module

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to replace some text inside a file with the python re module.

Here is the input value :

```html
<li><span class="PCap CharOverride-4">Contrôles</span> <span class="PCap CharOverride-4">Testes</span></li>
```

and the excepting output is this :

```html
<li><span class="PCap CharOverride-4">C<span style="font-size:83%">ONTRôLES</span></span>
<span class="PCap CharOverride-4">T<span style="font-size:83%">ESTES</span></span></li>
```

but insted, I get this as result :

```html
<li><span class="PCap CharOverride-4">C<span style="font-size:83%">ONTRôLES</span></span> <span class="PCap CharOverride-4">C<span style="font-size:83%">ONTRôLES</span></span></li>
```

Is there something that I missed ?

Here is what I've done so far :

```py
        for line in file_data.readlines():
    
            #print(line)
            reg = re.compile(r'(?P<b1>(<'+balise_name+' class="(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*?) |)'+class_value+')(| ([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*?))">)(?P<maj>([A-ZÀÁÂÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ]))(?P<min>([a-zàáâãäåæçèéëìíîïðòóôõöøùúûüýÿµœš]*?))(?P<b2>(<\/'+balise_name+'>))')
            #print(reg)
            search = reg.findall(line)

            print(search)

            if (search != None):
                for matchObj in search:
                
                    print(matchObj)
                    #print(matchObj[8])
                    print(line)
                
                    balise1  = matchObj[0] #search.group('b1')
                    print(balise1)
                
                    balise2 = matchObj[10] #matchObj.group('b2')
                    print(balise2)
                
                    maj = matchObj[6] #matchObj.group('maj')
                    print(maj)
                
                    min = matchObj[8] #matchObj.group('min')
                    print(min)
                    
                    sub_str = balise1+""+maj+"<span style=\"font-size:83%\">"+min.upper()+"</span>"+balise2

                    line = re.sub(reg, sub_str, line)
  
                    #ouverture du fichier pour ajour ligne
                    filename = file_name.split(".")
                    #file_result = open(filename[0]+"-OK."+filename[1], "a")
                    #file_result.writelines(line)

                    #file_data.writelines(line)
                    #file_result.close()

                    print(line)
```

NB : I don't know how to use the module Beautifulsoup of python so why I do it manually.

Pardon me for my poor english.

Thanks for your answer !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I totally forgot about this question but here is the solution I came up with after fixing the code I wrote long time ago :

```py
    for line in file_data.readlines():
        reg = re.compile(r'(?P<b1>(\<' + balise_name + ' class=\"(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*?) |)' + class_value +
                         ')(| ([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*?))\"\>)(?P<maj>([A-ZÀÁÂÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ]))(?P<min>([a-zàáâãäåæçèéëìíîïðòóôõöøùúûüýÿµœš]*?))(?P<b2>(\<\/' + balise_name + '\>))')

        print(line)
        while reg.search(line):
            search = reg.search(line)
            if search:
                print(search)

            while search:
                balise1 = search[0]  # search.group('b1')
                print('b1 : ' + str(balise1))

                balise2 = search[11]  # search.group('b2')
                print('b2 : ' + str(balise2))

                maj = search[7]  # search.group('maj')
                print('maj : ' + str(maj))

                min = search[9]  # search.group('min')
                print('min : ' + str(min))

                sub_str = search[1] + "" + maj + "<span style=\"font-size:83%\">" + min.upper() + \
                    "</span>" + balise2
                print(sub_str)
                line = re.sub(str(search[0]), sub_str, line)

                print(line)
                search = None
```

Here is what I changed with the code :

- Fix some unescaped char inside the pattern
- Iterate the result one by one
- Fix group number for the sub function

Hope it will help someone who faced the same problem as me.